# A character on a subgroup could be written as a difference with some character on the whole group, help on argumentation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $U \le G$ of odd order such that $N_G(U) = TU$
with $T = \langle t \rangle$ for some involution $t$ and assume that $U^g \ne U$ implies $U^g \cap U = 1$. Then I can not understand the following argument:

> Let $\hat \lambda : TU \to \mathbb C$ be a linear character on $TU$. Further set $S = TU \setminus T^U$ and suppose $N_G(S) = TU$ and for $g \notin N_G(S)$ we have $S^g \cap S = \emptyset$ and that $\hat \lambda$ is zero outside of $S$ and that
>   $$
>  ((1-\hat \lambda), (1-\hat\lambda))_{TU} = 2 \quad\mbox{and}\quad
>  (1_{TU}, (1- \hat\lambda))_{TU} = 1.
> $$
>   Then there exists some linear character $\Lambda : G \to \mathbb C$ such that $(1-\hat\lambda)^G = 1 - \Lambda$.

I have some difficulty following the last line, I do not comprehend: What is $(1 - \hat \lambda)^G$ and why does it equals $ 1 - \Lambda$ for some linear character on $G$?

So could anyone please explain what is happening here?? Thank you!

Comment: $(1 - \hat{\lambda})^G$ is an induced character.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you, but why does this equals $1 - \Lambda$ for some character $\Lambda$ on $G$. Is this obvious? I cannot connect to what is written before...

Comment: I think you need to use Frobenius Reciprocity.